# SDK Real Time Updates

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

How do i subscribe to real time updates (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime) with the sdk?

1) I want to be notified when a user has a new friend or when a friend "unfriend's" them and is no longer there friend

2) When somebody changes there name

3) When a user changes their picture

Cheers

Rob

Comment: You should give both solutions Prabir, not just mvc! Think about the webform users too .... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FacebookClient (v5 beta) or FacebookApp (v4) class to do the post to the graph endpoint specified [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/).

Then it's just a matter of creating a page with codebehind that handles the GET and POST requests that Facebook sends when notifying you of a change.